# In Pelican, how do I display the full latest article/post on the home page?

Tags: blogs, static-site, pelican

I'm using Pelican 4.2.0, and I'd like to *always display the full text of my latest blog post on the 'home' page*, then have other posts listed on a separate 'Articles' page. Is this a setting, a template configuration, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full-content versus summary display behavior is entirely managed in theme templates. The default `notmyidea` theme included with Pelican, for example, has an [index.html template](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/index.html) that shows the most recent full-content article at the top, followed by summaries of previous articles below. The [relevant line that displays the full article content](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/index.html#L12) contains the following template variable:

```
{{ article.content }}
```

… whereas the [line that shows article summaries](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/index.html#L35) instead uses the following template variable:

```
{{ article.summary }}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, that's very helpful. I left a reply on the repo Issue, too. It looks like my scenario is one that most canned Pelican themes don't accomodate 'out of the box'.